# BASH split variable in characters and print out space in for loop

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop, space

I am trying to create a fancy welcome message to be displayed when the terminal is opened. I have done it in Java with this code:

```
public void slowPrint() {
    String message = "Welcome, " + System.getProperty("user.name");

    try {
        for(int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
            System.out.print(message.charAt(i));
            Thread.sleep(50);
        }
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now, I am fairly new to bash but I've managed to make this code:

```
for i in W e l c o m e , $USER; do
    echo -ne $i
    sleep 0.05
done

echo !
```

There are two problems with this code:

1. I have no idea how to print a plain space after the comma, the output is just `Welcome,simon!` How can I make it output a space instead?
2. It, of course, prints `$USER` as a whole word. I would want it to be character by character, how can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a standard for loop to achieve the same effect:

```
MESSAGE="Welcome, $USER"
for (( i=0; i<${#MESSAGE}; i++ )); do
    echo -ne "${MESSAGE:$i:1}"
    sleep 0.05
done
echo !
```

The `${MESSAGE:$i:1}` syntax takes a substring of 1 from position `i` in the string. Enclosing that part in quotes ensures that things like spaces and tabs are also printed.

Comment: You forgot quotes, so the space isn't printed.

Comment: Should the `!` in `MESSAGE="...!"` raise an `event not found` error, you can assign the string like this: `MESSAGE="Welcome, $USER"'!'`

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the space easily enough; enclose it in quotes:

```
for i in W e l c o m e , ' ' ...
```

Splitting `$USER` into separate characters can be done many ways.  The way I'd do it is old-fashioned but reliable:

```
for i in W e l c o m e , ' ' $(sed 's/./& /g' <<< "$USER")
```

Note that the `<<<` operation saves a process and a pipe; it redirects standard input of `sed` so it reads the given string as a line of input.

Or, if you think the user name might contain any spaces or other special characters:

```
for i in W e l c o m e , ' ' $(sed "s/./'&' /g" <<< "$USER")
```

(This isn't bullet proof; the value `USER="Tam O'Shanter"` will cause some grief, and the simple fix for that runs into trouble with `USER='Will "O'\''Wisp" Light'` instead. ...mutter, mutter, arcane incantations, ...

```
    for i in W e l c o m e , ' ' $(sed "s/./'&' /g; s/'''/\\\\'/g" <<< "$USER")
```

except that echoes the name with single quotes around everything; grumble, grumble, ... I think I've just worked out why I wouldn't ever both to do this, ... spaces get in the way too ... I'd use the simple first version and tell people not to use blanks or special characters in the value of `$USER`.)

There <s>might be</s> ***are*** ways to do it without invoking a separate process such as `sed`; see the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15717563/15168) by [heuristicus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/499940/heuristicus).  So, do it that way.  But note that it is firmly tied to `bash` in a way that this answer isn't wholly tied to `bash` — you can easily replace the `<<<` notation (which is `bash`-only) with `echo "$USER" | ...` instead.

Comment: Why not `"$USER"` instead of `$USER`?

Comment: Laziness/oversight; and the expectation that there will be few user names containing two or more consecutive spaces that need to be preserved.

Comment: However, it might be a bad example to show to a bash beginner in case he applies this pattern elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Completely POSIXly portable, i.e. without those pesky bashisms, and no fork to sed:

```
#!/bin/sh

m="Welcome, $USER!"
while test ${#m} -gt 0; do
  r=${m#?}
  printf '%s ' "${m%%$r}"
  m=$r
  sleep 0.05
done
printf '\n'
```

Note that sleeping for fractions of a second is non-portable.